# Problema con menu en python

Tags: python

[PREGUNTA EDITADA] 
Hola que tal, espero que anden bien. Tengo un problema con los menú y sub-menú en Python. Les paso a explicar a lo que quiero llegar, quiero hacer un menú principal del cual tendrá su sub-menú y ese sub-menú tendrá a su vez otro sub-menú y así sucesivamente.

> Cuando me encuentro en un sub-menú y quiero volver al menu anterior. Luego se traba al volver a fichar una opcion

**CODIGO EN EJECUCION**

```
Selecciona una opción
    1 - ABML
    2 - Alta Paciente
    3 - Manejo de turnos
    9 - salir
inserta un numero valor >> 1
Selecciona una opción
    1 - Pacientes
    2 - Medicos
    3 - Habitaciones
    9 - salir
inserta un numero valor >> 9
Selecciona una opción
    1 - ABML
    2 - Alta Paciente
    3 - Manejo de turnos
    9 - salir
inserta un numero valor >> 1

Selecciona una opción
    1 - Pacientes
    2 - Medicos
    3 - Habitaciones
    9 - salir
Selecciona una opción
    1 - ABML
    2 - Alta Paciente
    3 - Manejo de turnos
    9 - salir
inserta un numero valor >>
```

Ese seria una vez ejecutado como se ve el menu principal consta de (ABML, Alta paciente y Manejo de turnos) inserto el valor 1 para ir al menu-ABML hasta ahi todo perfecto, desde el menuABML escojo la opcion 9 para volver al menu principal (Y vuelve!) pero cuando quiero entrar de vuelta al menuABML (ERROR! se imprime el menuABML y el menuprincipal simultaneamente)

Aqui les dejo el codigo de Menu.py (principal) y del Menu_ABML.py (menu abml)

***Menu.py***

```
import os

def menu():
    os.system('cls')
    print ("Selecciona una opción")
    print ("\t1 - ABML")
    print ("\t2 - Alta Paciente")
    print ("\t3 - Manejo de turnos")
    print ("\t9 - salir")

while True:
    opcionMenu = 0

    # Mostramos el menu
    menu()

    # solicituamos una opción al usuario
    opcionMenu = input("inserta un numero valor >> ")

    if opcionMenu=="1":
        from Menu_ABML import *
        print ("")
        menuABML()

    elif opcionMenu=="2":
        print ("")
        input("Has pulsado la opción 2...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
    elif opcionMenu=="3":
        print ("")
        input("Has pulsado la opción 3...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
    elif opcionMenu=="9":
        break
    else:
        print ("")
        input("No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
```

***Menu_ABML.py***

```
import os

def menuABML():
    os.system('cls')
    print ("Selecciona una opción")
    print ("\t1 - Pacientes")
    print ("\t2 - Medicos")
    print ("\t3 - Habitaciones")
    print ("\t9 - salir")

while True:
    # Mostramos el menu
    menuABML()

    # solicituamos una opción al usuario
    opcionMenu = input("inserta un numero valor >> ")

    if opcionMenu=="1":
        from Menu_Pacientes import *
        print ("")
        menuPACIENTES()

    elif opcionMenu=="2":
        from Menu_Medicos import *
        print ("")
        menuMEDICOS()

    elif opcionMenu=="3":
        from Menu_Habitaciones import *
        print ("")
        menuHABITACIONES()

    elif opcionMenu=="9":
        from Menu import *
        print ("")
        Menu()

    else:
        print ("")
        input("No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
```

Desde ya agradezco mucho, soy principiante en esto por el momento y me es de mucha ayuda su colaboración.

Comment: te sugiero sería utilizar CASE en lugar de IF.

Comment: yo no manejo python,pero porque es mejor CASE que if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación:

Básicamente el error se da porque cuando le das 9, se ejecuta `Menu()`, pero además el ciclo continúa, haciendo que se ejecute `MenuABL()` otra vez.

Para clarificar:

```
elif opcionMenu=="9":
   from Menu import *
   print ("")
   Menu()
```

Ese pedazo de código ejecuta `Menu()`, pero no cierra el ciclo, por lo que el ciclo va a la siguiente iteración que comienza con:

```
# Mostramos el menu
menuABML()
```

Y ejecuta `menuABL()`.

Es por eso que estás viendo `Menu` y `menuABL` dos veces.

#### Solución:

Tienes que parar la ejecución del ciclo una vez que se regresa a `Menu`, de lo contrario va a ejecutar `MenuABL` otra vez, para ello agrega un simple `break`, quedando así el código de **Menu_ABML.py**:

```
import os

def menuABML():
    os.system('cls')
    print ("Selecciona una opción")
    print ("\t1 - Pacientes")
    print ("\t2 - Medicos")
    print ("\t3 - Habitaciones")
    print ("\t9 - salir")

while True:
    # Mostramos el menu
    menuABML()

    # solicituamos una opción al usuario
    opcionMenu = input("inserta un numero valor >> ")

    if opcionMenu=="1":
        from Menu_Pacientes import *
        print ("")
        menuPACIENTES()

    elif opcionMenu=="2":
        from Menu_Medicos import *
        print ("")
        menuMEDICOS()

    elif opcionMenu=="3":
        from Menu_Habitaciones import *
        print ("")
        menuHABITACIONES()

    elif opcionMenu=="9":
        from Menu import *
        print ("")
        Menu()
        break # ----> aquí lo importante

    else:
        print ("")
        input("No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
```

Por último y como recomendación lee [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095071/in-python-what-happens-when-you-import-inside-of-a-function) y cambia los imports al inicio del programa así como está `import os`, no es muy bueno importarlos dentro de un ciclo.

## Update

Prueba con lo siguiente:

**Menu.py**

```
import os
from Menu_ABML import show_menu_ABML

def menu():
    os.system('cls')
    print("Selecciona una opción")
    print("\t1 - ABML")
    print("\t2 - Alta Paciente")
    print("\t3 - Manejo de turnos")
    print("\t9 - salir")

def show_main_menu():
    while True:
        opcionMenu = 0

        # Mostramos el menu
        menu()

        # solicituamos una opción al usuario
        opcionMenu = input("inserta un numero valor >> ")

        if opcionMenu == "1":
            print("")
            show_menu_ABML()

        elif opcionMenu == "2":
            print("")
            input("Has pulsado la opción 2...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
        elif opcionMenu == "3":
            print("")
            input("Has pulsado la opción 3...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
        elif opcionMenu == "9":
            break
        else:
            print("")
            input("No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    show_main_menu()
```

**Menu_ABML.py**

```
import os

def menuABML():
    os.system('cls')
    print("Selecciona una opción")
    print("\t1 - Pacientes")
    print("\t2 - Medicos")
    print("\t3 - Habitaciones")
    print("\t9 - salir")

def show_menu_ABML():
    while True:
        # Mostramos el menu
        menuABML()

        # solicituamos una opción al usuario
        opcionMenu = input("inserta un numero valor >> ")

        if opcionMenu == "1":
            print("Menú de los pacientes")

        elif opcionMenu == "2":
            print("Menú de los médicos")

        elif opcionMenu == "3":
            print("Menú de alguien")

        elif opcionMenu == "9":
            print("")
            break

        else:
            print("")
            input("No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
```

Ese código como está hace lo que quieres, básicamente lo que hice fue meter los ciclos dentro de funciones para que se pueden llamar en cualquier momento.

Si no están dentro de la función y su `scope` es global sólo se van a ejecutar en 2 ocasiones:

- Al correr el archivo que los contiene
- Al importar el archivo que los contiene (esta es la razón de lo que dice al final de tu primer comentario)

**Más recomendaciones**:

En el ciclo de ABML no llames a `Menu()` porque es la misma función que llamó al ciclo de ABML, y esto después de un tiempo te va a generar un error porque el stack va a llegar a su límite, un ejemplo de esta situación:

-- Ejecución de `Menu()` -> se entra al programa

----- Ejecución del `ciclo de ABML` -> se elige ABML

-------- Ejecución de `Menu()` -> se elige salir

----------- Ejecución del `ciclo de ABML` -> se vuelve a elegir ABML

-------------- Ejecución de `Menu` -> se elige salir nuevamente

----------------- ...... y así hasta terminar el programa

Y al final el stack va a tener muchas funciones, que te van a estar ocupando recursos y obviamente es malo para el performance. Lo ideal sería hacer lo siguiente:

-- Ejecución de `Menu()` -> se entra al programa

------ Ejecución del `ciclo ABML` -> se elige ABML

------ Termina el `ciclo ABML` -> se elige salir

-- Continúa el ciclo de `Menu()`

------ Ejecución del `ciclo ABML` -> se elige ABML otra vez

------ Termina el `ciclo ABML` -> se elige salir nuevamente

-- Continúa el ciclo de `Menu()`

------  ..... y así hasta terminar el programa

De esta forma el stack ya no está tan cargado como la forma anterior.

Esta última forma está implementada en el update.

Por último te recomiendo hacer tus programas de python de forma modular, casi todos están hechos de esa forma, [lee esto](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_modules.asp)

Comment: He hecho lo que me haz dicho sobre incluir el break para cortar el ciclo en la opción 9 y también puse todos los import en la parte superior. Pero sigue sin funcionar por alguna razón. Acaso sera era el compilador?. De hecho eh provado la diferencia entre poner el import en la parte superior y el import en la condicional y cuando esta en la parte superior es como que se ejecuta inmediatamente la función que se encuentra en el primer import evadiendo el código debajo

Comment: No no puede ser el compilador, revisa el update en la respuesta y sólo modificalo de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Benjamin ahi prove tu codigo anda perfecto muchisimas gracias!!!!! Ahora mismo modifico todos los menus !!!

Comment: Qué bueno, acabo de agregarle una recomendación a la respuesta sobre el performance, si puedes leela.

Comment: Gracias benja !!! Si al final no llame al menu principal simplemente deje el break así no se cargaba tanto! Gracias por los tips los tendré muy en cuenta =)!!!!!

Comment: Una ultima consulta, es que necesito llamar un modulo pero esta en otra carpeta y cuando lo llamo con el import me tira error con la dirección del modulo he intentado colocar la direccion de la carpeta dentro del from pero no hubo caso, anduve investigando y resulta que me encuentro con que se tiene que utilizar un archivo gloval llamado _init_.py pero resulta que yo no lo tengo dentro de las carpetas. Sabes algo sobre eso???

Comment: Modificar init.py me parece que va a cambiar todo lo de python, no sólo lo que estás trabajando, checa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955684/how-to-import-py-file-from-another-directory) como ahí mismo dice, es la solución más fácil. Si eso no ayuda, revisa el nombre de la carpeta, que no tenga caracteres raros (como acentos, ñ's, o algo así)